# FTP image not showing

Tags: html, ftp

I am maintaining a website and for this site I have recently uploaded some new images through FileZilla. The images are uploaded and I can see them through FileZilla, yet when I open my site through a browser only some of my images show, even though they have similar paths and locations, so it is not a broken link. I have looked around StackOverflow and google but I couldn't fin any answers, besides I have cleared my cache and tried on multiple devices. The HTML to display the images is:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="/img/fysio1.jpg">
    <img src="/img/fysio2.jpg">
    <img src="/img/fysio3.jpg">
</div>
```

But i'm pretty sure that this is not the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your browser's console. You probably get a 403 or 404. Probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Or a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: the permissions are all the same as FileZilla shows but i'll go check the console

Comment: @Quentin Thank you so much! Such a dumb mistake of me, it was indeed case sensitivity, that's probably why it did work on my local server since that one i not case sensitive. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my hosting company has case-sensitivity when it comes to pictures whilst apache hasn't. So changing the file names to lower-case did the job.

Comment: Linux hase case sensitive file names while Windows hasn't. I assume your local PC has Windows and your hosting company Linux (or Unix). This isn't about Apache. See also http://superuser.com/questions/881804/case-sensitive-file-extensions-in-windows-and-linux